# Extending lines from Cyclic Quadilateral

Tags: geometry

Take a cyclic quadilateral, ABCD. Line BD bisects angle ABC. Extend the side BA beyond A to a point H. Show that DH = DB only if AH = BC.

I've attempted to draw this out, but anything I've drawn is a dead end. Any guidance or solutions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Despite that, you should still draw a diagram to aid your thoughts. It would be easier to draw this by first drawing points $A,B,C$, the angle bisector and their circumcircle. Do you see any equal sides/angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$CD\cong AD$ because angles $CBD$ and $ABD$ are congruent as $BD$ is bisector.

$BC\cong AH$ by hypothesis.

$BCD$ and $DAB$ are supplementary because $ABCD$ is cyclic, thus $BCD\cong DAH$.

Therefore triangles $CBD$ and $DAH$ are congruent and $BD\cong DH$.

[image]